# Best way to implement a slide show with remote media inside a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need your help to implement a part of my current app.

There is a recyclerview. Each item may have some media files related to it. All of these related media files are stored on a remote server. They can be an image, a video or a youtube video.
A item may have none media file related or several media files related. For example,item #1 has an image, item #2 has two images, item #3 has 2 images, 1 video and 1 youtube video, and item #4 has no image related.

I need to add all media related files from each item as slideshow inside each item view.
I have tried using a viewpager, but I am getting problems with the viewpager adapter. May be the problem is the download time from the files, but I guess a viewpager is not the best solution for my purpose.
Here is the code where the recyclerview adapter is getting the media files from a hashmap:

```
   String mediapostfile []= mediafile.split(",");

        String mediaposttype []= mediatype.split(",");

        Hash_file_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post id_post "+id_post);
        Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post id_post ****************");


        for ( int w=0  ;w < mediapostfile.length;w++){
            if (mediapostfile[w].equals("null")){

                Hash_file_maps.put("vacio", url_postmedia+"noimage.jpg");
                Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post sin imagen "+id_post);

            }
            else {
                if (mediaposttype[w].equals("2")){

                    Hash_file_maps.put("video."+mediapostfile[w], url_postmedia+"esvideo.png");
                    Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post video "+id_post);

                }
                if (mediaposttype[w].equals("1")) {

                    Hash_file_maps.put("imagen."+mediapostfile[w], url_postmedia+mediapostfile[w]);
                    Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post imagen "+id_post);

                }
                if (mediaposttype[w].equals("3")){

                    Hash_file_maps.put("youtube."+mediapostfile[w], url_postmedia+"youtubevideo.png");
                    Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post youtube "+id_post);

                }
            }

        }
        Log.d("estoy en el post ","estoy en el post id_post --------------------------");
```

I have included some logs to verify that each item receives the related media files, and this part of the code is working, that means that each time an item is shown in the screen, the related media files are listed.

I need to know the best option I have to create a slideshow with all media related to each item.
I already have the methods to show a remote image, to play a remote video and to play a youtube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using view pager better to use exoplayer with some customization and adding click events and listener etc as per the requirement.

and add multiple images and videos using `ConcatenatingMediaSource`

Use `exoplayer-ui:x.x.x` and `SimpleExoPlayerView` has built in image view.
you can set your image with default_artwork attribute in xml, for example:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/playerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:default_artwork="@drawable/default_media_artwork"
    app:use_artwork="true"/>
```

Hope to be useful.

Comment: Taking into account that what I get here is a hashmap with the media type (and url from each media (image,video,youtube video),  do you mean I could add this exoplayerview and get this work as a slideshow from all media?